# google map with search in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, google-map-react

I'm using [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) library for maps in my react application, and I'm adding search address functionality in my application and facing CORS error.

Error:
[image]

Autocomplete.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
`;

class AutoComplete extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.clearSearchBox = this.clearSearchBox.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount({ map, mapApi } = this.props) {
        const options = {
            // restrict your search to a specific type of result
            types: ['address'],
            // restrict your search to a specific country, or an array of countries
            // componentRestrictions: { country: ['gb', 'us'] },
        };
        this.autoComplete = new mapApi.places.Autocomplete(
            this.searchInput,
            options,
        );
        this.autoComplete.addListener('place_changed', this.onPlaceChanged);
        this.autoComplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    }

    componentWillUnmount({ mapApi } = this.props) {
        mapApi.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.searchInput);
    }

    onPlaceChanged = ({ map, addplace } = this.props) => {
        const place = this.autoComplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry) return;
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }

        addplace(place);
        this.searchInput.blur();
    };

    clearSearchBox() {
        this.searchInput.value = '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <input
                    className="search-input"
                    ref={(ref) => {
                        this.searchInput = ref;
                    }}
                    type="text"
                    onFocus={this.clearSearchBox}
                    placeholder="Enter a location"
                />
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

Google Map Component:

```
const MyGoogleMap = () => {
    const [apiReady, setApiReady] = useState(false);
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const [mapApi, setMapApi] = useState(null);
    const [address, setAddress] = useState();
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState();
    const [center, setCenter] = useState([]);
    const [lat, setLat] = useState();
    const [lng, setLng] = useState();
    const [places, setPlaces] = useState();
    const [draggable, setDraggable] = useState();

    const setCurrentLocation = () => {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                console.log('position.coords: ', position.coords.longitude);
                console.log("[position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]: ", [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
                setCenter([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
                setLat(position.coords.latitude);
                setLng(position.coords.longitude);
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentLocation();
    }, []);

    const handleApiLoaded = (map, maps) => {
        console.log('map, maps: ', map, maps);
        // use map and maps objects
        if (map && maps) {
            setApiReady(true);
            setMap(map);
            setMapApi(maps);
        }
    };
    const _generateAddress = () => {
        const geocoder = new mapApi.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ location: { lat: lat, lng: lng } }, (results, status) => {
            console.log(results);
            console.log(status);
            if (status === 'OK') {
                if (results[0]) {
                    setZoom(12);
                    setAddress(results[0].formatted_address);
                } else {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });
    };

    const onMarkerInteraction = (childKey, childProps, mouse) => {
        setDraggable(true);
        setLat(mouse.lat);
        setLng(mouse.lng);
    };

    const onMarkerInteractionMouseUp = (childKey, childProps, mouse) => {
        setDraggable(true);
        _generateAddress();
    };

    const _onChange = ({ center, zoom }) => {
        setZoom(zoom);
        setCenter(center);
    };

    const _onClick = value => {
        setLat(value.lat);
        setLng(value.lng);
    };

    const addPlace = place => {
        setPlaces([place]);
        setLat(place.geometry.location.lat());
        setLng(place.geometry.location.lng());
        _generateAddress();
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ height: '442px', width: '100%' }}>
            {apiReady && <Autocomplete map={map} mapApi={mapApi} addplace={addPlace} />}
            <GoogleMapReact
                zoom={4}
                center={center}
                bootstrapURLKeys={{
                    key: 'API_KEY',
                    libraries: ['places', 'geometry'],
                }}
                yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
                onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) =>
                    handleApiLoaded(map, maps)
                }
            ></GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm following this [article](https://www.freakyjolly.com/google-maps-in-react-example-application/) to integrate Google Maps with search

Comment: You may want to check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180788/how-to-use-cors-to-implement-javascript-google-places-api-request

Comment: Did you sorted it out? Having the same problem