# CORS with Place API maps

Tags: vue.js, maps, google-places-api

I got a problem with place API, I want to call `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?&location=50.6288692%2C3.0621601&type=gym&key=[YOUR_KEY]`
I try with axios, and also with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` but I always got my CORS error.

I try to call with [https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps] but place is not find when I make
`new google.maps.place`

Have you an idea ? :)

Comment: Check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182716/6700091)

Comment: The problem is when I adding script in my index.html, I got 'google' is undefined error when running my project

Comment: Just as what the answer that @KamilBęben sent, I'm guessing that you are trying to use the Google Places API on client side? Is that correct?