# CORS Error when using Google Maps API Place Search in `fetch`

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, cors

### Quesiton:

I have a small project that I am wanting to make that goes through a list of (around 300) names of places, and gets details about these places using the Google Maps Place Search API. If I take one of these places, and place the URL in my browser:

```js
/* Replacing API_KEY with my API key
   and PLACE_NAME with each place name */
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=API_KEY&query=PLACE_NAME"
```

When I put that in my browser, it gives me the JSON result, just as we expect.

The problem I am having is in my `<script>` tag in my HTML file. Where I do the following:

```js
let result = await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=API_KEY&query=PLACE_NAME')
```

But I get the following CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=API_KEY&query=PLACE_NAME' from origin 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I know very little about CORS and how to fix these kinds of errors. I've tried searching the web for solutions, but the things I found either didn't work for my project (e.g. importing a library using `require()`) or was about a different Google Maps API. And obviously setting it to a `no-cors` request is *NOT* what I want, as I will not be able to see the results.

---

### Solution:

As this question was closed because it is a duplicate question, I wanted to edit my question to share the solution, because the answer to the question this is a duplicate of, points to the solution, but doesn't answer it.

The answer to that question talks about how the way I was trying was for a Web Service. There is the [Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), which is how you need to do this sort of thing client-side.

1. Enable the Google Maps API on your Google Cloud dashboard.
2. Import the Google Maps JavaScript Library:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=callBackFunction"></script>
```

3. Then write your function (in another `<script>` tag) and create a new `PlacesService`

```js
function getLocationData() {
    // Because PlacesService requires a div or map element, we create this
    const element = document.createElement('div');

    // Create a new instance of PlaceService to use it's methods
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(element);

    // Use one of it's methods. In my case I need findPlaceFromQuery
    service.findPlaceFromQuery(
        // Choose what fields you want it to return (if the method requires)
        { fields: ['geometry'], query: data[i].name },
        (results) => {
            // Do your data processing here
        })
}
```

And now it should work!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use CORS to implement JavaScript Google Places API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180788/how-to-use-cors-to-implement-javascript-google-places-api-request)

Comment: an easy way around this if you have PHP is to issue the `fetch` request to a PHP script that fetches the remote url

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for pointing me to that question, I tried searching for a solution here on SO, but somehow that question evaded me. It didn't quite give me the solution, but it ***did*** point me to what I needed.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius As my project is a frontend project, that won't work for me. Thank you for sharing though.