# Google Map React Api Cors Issue

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, cors

Im using react-google-maps/api@2.18.1 to implement Google Map in my project. There are some problems with my implementaton when i always get cors problem when i tried to zoom in/ zoom out or find any places with maps. Do anyone know which is happening and how can i resolve it?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT9Zr.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8NpN.png)

[My implementation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAtgl.png)
[My implementation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieWj7.png)

Find a solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: Probably your Google Maps API key is restricted: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Hi, My key is unrestricted. I didnt set any restriction on this key...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue you are experiencing. Posting photos of code is against the Stack Overflow community guidelines on asking questions. Please refer to the aforementioned links to improve your questions and increase your chance of getting help. Usually this is the reason why CORS error happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182716/18422887