# Get business rating over Google places API in Javascript (Client-Side)

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I need to get a rating of a client and add it to a div. But i get an error in the console. How can i do this easily?

My Code:

```
/***** GOOGLE MY-BUSINESS / PLACES-DATA *****/
const apiKey = 'KEY-pHws-3qK0cCkhuTKRx7Zo';
const placeId = 'ID'; // Replace with the actual place ID of the company
  
const placeUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${placeId}&fields=name,rating&key=${apiKey}`;  
  
fetch(placeUrl)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const rating = data.result.rating;
    console.log(rating);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

The error:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same-Origin Policy disallows reading the external resource."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CORS to implement JavaScript Google Places API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180788/how-to-use-cors-to-implement-javascript-google-places-api-request)

Comment: Hmm i didnt really find a solution that works. The last one is the best but they really need to add a map. I just need to get the rating value in a js variable.

Comment: The non-accepted answers are hacky attempts to work around the fact that you're using the wrong API as explained in the accepted answer.  Please read the accepted answer carefully and follow it's advice as it applies directly to your question as well.

Comment: Plus https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827564 confirmed this in 2015: CORS headers are not supported for Places API.